# In Open Source Parse DashBoard Files are not Uploading

Tags: parse-platform, dashboard

I am using open source Parse Dashboard after migrating my app from Parse.But now I have problem that when I click on Upload File in File is selected by File chooser but Files not uploaded in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add javaScriptkey in index.js of ParseDashboard where appId and clientKey added.